# How to get the DDL/Source code of a function in Oracle Enterprise Manager (OEM)

Tags: oracle, ddl, oracle-enterprise-manager

Sometimes we are unable to fetch a source code via dbms_metadata.get_ddl the package then we can use OEM as another way to generate DDL

Answer (score 1):

After Login to OEM Console -> Select Target -> Databases -> select database ->  follow the screenshot.

**Screenshot 1:**
[image]

**Screenshot 2:**
[image]

**Screenshot 3:**
[image]

**Screenshot 4:**
[image]

**Screenshot 5:** (Login with sys as sysdba role)
[image]

**Screenshot 6:** (Search the object and select **generate DDL** from drop down then click on **Go**)
[image]

**Screenshot 7:** (Here is your source code)
[image]

Now here is the final source code of select function from OEM, like that you can generate the source code of other objects as well.